# how to assign words to a number in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a below dataframe with numbers in two of the columns and I should replace that with string using my other reference dataset.

Dataset 1:

```
lhs         rhs 
32,39,6     65  
39,6,65     32  
14,16,26    15
16,20,4     26  
16,26,33    4   
53          31
```

Dataset 2:

```
id   name
4   yougurt
6   coffee
14  cream chese
15  meat spreads
16  butter
20  whole milk
26  condensed milk
31  curd
32  flour
39  rolls
53  sugar
65  soda
```

Expected output:

```
lhs                                     rhs
flour, rolls, coffee                   soda
rolls, coffee, soda                    flour
cream chease, butter, condensed milk   meat spreads
```

Comment: What is the class of the `lhs` column in your input and desired output? Character? List?

Comment: @Ryan its a character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option. Here `d1` is your first data frame and `d2` your second.

```
library(tidyverse)
d1 %>% separate(lhs, sep = ',', into = c('v1', 'v2', 'v3')) %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% 
  left_join(d2, by = c('v1'='id')) %>% 
  left_join(d2, by = c('v2'='id')) %>%
  left_join(d2, by = c('v3'='id')) %>% 
  left_join(d2, by = c('rhs'='id')) %>%
  unite(lhs, name.x, name.y, name.x.x, sep = ',') %>%
  mutate(lhs = str_replace_all(lhs, ',NA', '')) %>%
  select(lhs, rhs = name.y.y)
```

OR, as pointed out by @Moody_Mudskipper in the comments

```
d1 %>% separate(lhs, sep = ',', into = c('v1', 'v2', 'v3')) %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% 
  lmap(~setNames(left_join(setNames(.x, "id"), d2)[2], names(.x))) %>%
  unite(lhs, v1, v2, v3, sep = ', ') %>%
  mutate(lhs = str_replace_all(lhs, ',NA', '')) %>%
  select(lhs, rhs = name.y.y)


                                     lhs              rhs
1                  flour,  rolls, coffee             soda
2                   rolls, coffee,  soda            flour
3   cream chese, butter,  condensed milk     meat spreads
4            butter, whole milk, yougurt   condensed milk
5                butter,  condensed milk          yougurt
6                                  sugar             curd
```

Comment: I played a bit with your answer to see if I could avoid the redundancy of the left join and got to this: `dat1 %>% separate(lhs, sep = ',', into = c('v1', 'v2', 'v3')) %>% mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% lmap(~setNames(left_join(setNames(.x,"id"),dat2)[2],names(.x))) %>% unite(lhs, v1,v2,v3, sep = ', ') %>% mutate(lhs = str_replace_all(lhs, ', NA', ''))`

Answer (score 4):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr). `dat` is the final output. The key is to use `separate_rows` to expand the `lhs` and then conduct `left_join` twice.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- dat1 %>%
  separate_rows(lhs, convert = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(dat2, by = c("lhs" = "id")) %>%
  left_join(dat2, by = c("rhs" = "id")) %>%
  drop_na(name.x) %>%
  group_by(name.y) %>%
  summarise(lhs = paste0(name.x, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(lhs, rhs = name.y)

dat
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   lhs                                 rhs           
#   <chr>                               <chr>         
# 1 butter, whole milk, yougurt         condensed milk
# 2 sugar                               curd          
# 3 rolls, coffee, soda                 flour         
# 4 cream chese, butter, condensed milk meat spreads  
# 5 flour, rolls, coffee                soda          
# 6 butter, condensed milk              yougurt
```

**DATA**

```
dat1 <- read.table(text = "lhs         rhs 
'32,39,6'     65  
'39,6,65'     32  
'14,16,26'    15
'16,20,4'     26  
'16,26,33'    4   
53          31  ",
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

dat2 <- read.table(text = "id   name
4   yougurt
                   6   coffee
                   14  'cream chese'
                   15  'meat spreads'
                   16  butter
                   20  'whole milk'
                   26  'condensed milk'
                   31  curd
                   32  flour
                   39  rolls
                   53  sugar
                   65  soda",
                   header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is almost the same as www, but appears to be a little faster. Apparently using `strsplit` and `unnest` is faster than `separate_rows`

```
require(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(lhs = sapply(lhs, strsplit, ',')) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  mutate_at(c('lhs', 'rhs'), as.numeric) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c('lhs'= 'id')) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c('rhs'= 'id')) %>% 
  group_by(name.y) %>% 
  summarize(name.x = paste(name.x, collapse = ', ')) %>% 
  rename(rhs = name.y, lhs = name.x)
```

Then there's the `data.table` solution, which is much faster.

```
require(data.table) 
setDT(df1)

df1[, .(lhs = unlist(strsplit(lhs, ','))), rhs] %>% 
  .[, lapply(.SD, as.numeric)] %>% 
  merge(df2, by.x = 'lhs', by.y = 'id') %>% 
  merge(df2, by.x = 'rhs', by.y = 'id') %>% 
  .[, .(lhs = paste0(name.x, collapse = ',')), by = .(rhs = name.y)]
```

Benchmark

```
# Results
# Unit: relative
#               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#            useDT() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   300
#        UseUnnest() 5.570704 5.632532 5.274552 5.374714 5.042518 9.254190   300
#  UseSeparateRows() 8.640615 8.356889 7.661669 7.939593 7.401666 7.896038   300

# Method
require(tidyverse)
require(data.table) 

df1 <- fread("
lhs         rhs 
32,39,6     65  
39,6,65     32  
14,16,26    15
16,20,4     26  
16,26,33    4   
53          31  
")
df2 <- fread("
id   name
4   yougurt
6   coffee
14  cream_chese
15  meat_spreads
16  butter
20  whole_milk
26  condensed_milk
31  curd
32  flour
39  rolls
53  sugar
65  soda
")


useDT <- function(x){

df1[, lapply(sapply(lhs, strsplit, ','), unlist), rhs] %>% 
  setNames(c('rhs', 'lhs')) %>% 
  .[, `:=`(lhs = as.numeric(lhs),
           rhs = as.numeric(rhs))] %>% 
  .[df2, on = c('lhs'= 'id')] %>% 
  .[df2, on = c('rhs'= 'id')] %>% 
  .[, .(lhs = paste0(name, collapse = ',')), by = i.name] %>% 
  .[lhs != 'NA', .(lhs, rhs = i.name)]
}


UseUnnest <- function(x){
df1 %>% 
  mutate(lhs = sapply(lhs, strsplit, ',')) %>% 
  unnest %>%
  mutate_at(c('lhs', 'rhs'), as.numeric) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c('lhs'= 'id')) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c('rhs'= 'id')) %>% 
  group_by(name.y) %>% 
  summarize(name.x = paste(name.x, collapse = ', ')) %>% 
  rename(rhs = name.y, lhs = name.x)
}

UseSeparateRows <- function(x){
  df1 %>%
  separate_rows(lhs, convert = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("lhs" = "id")) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("rhs" = "id")) %>%
  drop_na(name.x) %>%
  group_by(name.y) %>%
  summarise(lhs = paste0(name.x, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(lhs, rhs = name.y)
}


microbenchmark(useDT(), UseUnnest(), UseSeparateRows(), times = 300, unit = 'relative')
```

Comment: you might go yet a little faster by using `vapply` or `map_chr` instead of `sapply`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using just base R and mapping the numeric values to factor labels.
Split the string, map the labels to the values and then collapse the labels back into a string.

```
df<-structure(list(id = c(4L, 6L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 20L, 26L, 31L, 32L, 
     39L, 53L, 65L), name = c("yougurt", "coffee", "cream cheese", 
     "meat spreads", "butter", "whole milk", "condensed milk", "curd", 
     "flour", "rolls", "sugar", "soda")), .Names = c("id", "name"), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

input<-structure(list(lhs = c("32,39,6", "39,6,65", "14,16,26", "16,20,4", 
    "16,26,33", "53"), rhs = c(65L, 32L, 15L, 26L, 4L, 31L)), 
    .Names = c("lhs", "rhs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

#new left hand side
newlhs<-sapply(as.character(input$lhs), function(x){
  strs<-unlist(strsplit(x, ","))
  f<-factor(strs, levels=df$id, labels=df$name)
  paste(f, collapse = ", ")
})

#new right hand side
newrhs<-sapply(as.character(input$rhs), function(x){
  strs<-unlist(strsplit(x, ","))
  f<-factor(strs, levels=df$id, labels=df$name)
  paste(f, collapse = ", ")
})

answer<-data.frame(newlhs, newrhs)
row.names(answer)<-NULL  #remove rownames
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so idiomatic but I win the code golf :) :

```
as.data.frame(lapply(dat1, function(x){
  for (i in seq(nrow(dat2))) x <- gsub(paste0("(^|,)",dat2$id[i],"(,|$)"),
                                       paste0("\\1",dat2$name[i],"\\2"),x)
  x}))
#                                 lhs            rhs
# 1                flour,rolls,coffee           soda
# 2                 rolls,coffee,soda          flour
# 3 cream chese,butter,condensed milk   meat spreads
# 4         butter,whole milk,yougurt condensed milk
# 5          butter,condensed milk,33        yougurt
# 6                             sugar           curd
```

May fail if you have numbers in 2nd dataset.